# How to Convert C# Variable DateTime Into SqlDbType.DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

How to convert a C# DateTime variable into Enum of SqlDataType.DateTime?

How to consume that enum into a connection string?

Is doing something like this correct?

```
string str = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CreateDt " + <that enum>;
SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection (<connection setting>);
Table = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Connection);
adapter.FillSchema(Table, SchemaType.Source);
adapter.Fill(Table);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is to use a parameterized command:

```
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            DateTime MyDate = DateTime.Now;

            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CreateDt = @MyDate";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyDate", @MyDate);

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.FillSchema(Table, SchemaType.Source);
            adapter.Fill(Table);
```

Comment: is this command text allows alteration for example doing sth like cmd.CommandText **+=** "AND FinishDt = @MyDate";

Comment: if i use Command Text, how shall I fill a datatable using that connection? (like the 1 I use show in my question)

Comment: Sorry, I was getting the correct syntax for that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I receive sqldatetime overflow error when i test this code, any idea how it happen?

Comment: This will definitely happen if the date/time you are passing has not been set to a valid value. This is because in this case, the DateTime parameter will default to DateTime.MinValue (1/1/0001), which is far below the allowable minimum in SQL Server, which is 1/1/1753.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6450/discussion-between-rofans-net-and-competent-tech)

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested, but how about:

```
string str = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CreateDt = @createDate";

SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection (<connection setting>);

Table mytable = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Connection);

adapter .SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@createDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
adapter .SelectCommand.Parameters("@createDate").Value = <Some DateTime>

adapter.FillSchema(mytable, SchemaType.Source);
adapter.Fill(Table);
```